# New to Java and would like someone to help me with this

Tags: java, class, import

I'm new to the Java language, Can someone help me with this question.

The question goes like this:

Objective: Review concepts of reading and writing objects to files 
Information of cars is provided in a text file, as given below. 
File Name : honda.txt 
CRV-3     CV6787272     150000.00       20.0

MRV-1     MV9890202     180000.00       20.0

Civic     CC9939390     82000.00        10.0

CRV-3     CV8393939     149000.00       20.0

Step 1  Create a class named “Car” which has the following fields. The fields correspond to the columns in the text file except the last one.

a.  Vehicle Name : String

b.  Engine Number : String

c.  Vehicle Price : double

d.  Profit : double v.

e.  Total Price : double (Total Price = (Vehicle Price) + (Vehicle Price* Profit/100)

Step 2  Update the Car class with methods to do the following

a.  To read the content of the text file (honda.txt)

i.  For each row in the file an instance of the class Car is created with the calculated Total Price.

ii. Write each instance created to another file, "honda_showroom.txt".

b.  Display the contents of “honda_showroom.txt”

i.  A method ex: showCar(String eNumber), takes the Engine Number as parameter. And displays all the information of the particular car including Total Price. 
Step 3  Create a Main class to test the above.

**The code I've written so far:**

*Car Class Code (Written in BlueJ):*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Car {

private String vehicleName;
private String engineNumber;
private double vehiclePrice;
private double Profit;
private double totalPrice;
totalPrice = (vehiclePrice) + ((vehiclePrice * Profit) / 100);



public double getProfit() {
    return Profit;
}

public void setProfit(double Profit) {
    this.Profit = Profit;
}

public String getEngineNumber() {
    return engineNumber;
}

public void setEngineNumber(String engineNumber) {
    this.engineNumber = engineNumber;
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}

public String getVehicleName() {
    return vehicleName;
}

public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
    this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
}

public double getVehiclePrice() {
    return vehiclePrice;
}

public void setVehiclePrice(double vehiclePrice) {
    this.vehiclePrice = vehiclePrice;
}
}
```

*Output or display class:*

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
public class Display {

private String fileName;

public Display(String fName) {
    // this.fileName = "honda_showroom";
    fileName = fName;
    // this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public void showCar(String eNumber) throws FileNotFoundException,     IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(this.fileName));
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Car> cList = (ArrayList<Car>) ois.readObject();


    while (ois.readObject() != null) {

        cList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        int searchListLength = cList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
            if (cList.get(i).equals(eNumber)) {
                cList.toString();
            }

         }
     }
 }
 }
```

Thanks in advance! and please keep in mind that I'm a beginner also gathered some codes from the internet.

Comment: Well ... much text, much code. But is there any question you have?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I expected to see some much lesser quality code.

I think the first trouble is:

```
private double totalPrice;
totalPrice = (vehiclePrice) + ((vehiclePrice * Profit) / 100);
```

The assignment statement does not compile. At that level immediate below `class { ... }` you may only declare fields, methods, constructors (and initializers).

You could place it in a constructor or method:

```
public void updateTotalPrice() {
    totalPrice = vehiclePrice + vehiclePrice * Profit / 100;
}
```

Now totalPrice is entirely depending on the actual current values of the formula's variables. So maybe it should be a method instead, always calculating its value.

The second problem is with file I/O. Of course one should use the means learned already. So it is a bit hard for me, and probably you should investigate it yourself.

I would have read **text** using a Reader:

```
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
BufferedReader in = Files.new BufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
...
in.close();
```

Or

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Similar [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) can write text.

Writing as binary data, as you are doing, cannot be checked as easy - too much magic.

---

***After comment***

Some courses use a Scanner instead of a simple (BufferedReader); that can read typed values. The BufferedReader would go as follows:

```
for (;;) {
    String line = in.readLine(); // null when at end; no newline chars
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    String[] fields = line.split(" ", 4);
    if (fields.length == 4) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setVehicleName(fields[0]);
        ...
        car.setProfit(Double.parseDouble(fields[3]);
        cList.add(car);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain where to include the Reader?

Comment: On reading the text file reading the cars. If you mean how it would work; I have added the tools usable: `BufferedReader.readLine, String.split, Double.parseDouble`. If you learned about Scanner, use that one.